# Multiple environments .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core project and I need to manage multiple environments. Let's say I have Development, Staging and Production environment. I have to manage different variables for each environment. In my `Startup.cs` I have already managed to have `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json` working, so that when i start my application with `--launch-profile "ProfileName"` I have the right configuration.

Now my problem is that I have to deploy this solution, so I have to do something like `dotnet publish --launch-profile "ProfileName"`; *i know that this syntax doesn't exist*, that's why I am asking this question. **I can't set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable machine wide on the host**, since I have multiple deploys (with multiple environments) on the same machine. I need a way to deploy with the right profile, so that the right `appsettings.json` is recognized by the right application. Thank you.

Comment: One way would be to run the different environments under different service accounts, and set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable on the user scope, rather than system wide. Depending on your environment and how you start the applications, you might also be able to set it for the specific process only.

Comment: So i guess there is not a way to declare a specific profile when you run dotnet publish

Comment: Have you considered setting Environment via the launching command line (rather than the publish command)? E.g. dotnet.exe myapp.dll Environment=Staging. Note there's a bug were you'd have to and commands line config in Main.

Comment: @Tratcher then in my app where i can retrieve Environment?

Comment: If you load it into the configuration system then the host will process it for you. See https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/221#issuecomment-335207431

Comment: I will try and notify you, thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the dotnet command on the host machine, so i can't run your option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `dotnet publish` does not provide possibility to deploy specific version of configuration file for specified environment. And I believe it's good because follows separation of concerns principle.

You still have several options for covering your use case:

1.Powershell allows setting environment variable only for current PowerShell session with `$Env` command.
You could create simple powershell launcher that sets `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable and then launches the application:

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Production"
# Command for launching your application
```

`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable will be accessible only within current session and will not conflict will other deployments of your application.

This solution is somehow similar to approach suggested by Tomas Lycken, but does not require creation of service account for each environment.

2.You could also shift away from dynamic selection of configuration file (`appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json`). You could put all environment-specific settings to one file (e.g. `appSettings.environemntSpecific.json`) and deploy only one version required for some particular environment (e.g. Development or Production). In this case you don't need setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` at all.

To do this, load new configuration file from `BuildWebHost` method:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appSettings.environemntSpecific.json", optional: true);
        }).UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

The final step here is to put required version of `appSettings.environemntSpecific.json` file after `dotnet publish` command. Again, `dotnet publish` does not provide any possibility for such selection, so you should do it by yourself with simplest `copy` command.

Comment: Just one more question, isn't web.config transformation an option? And how can it be done with .NET Core?

Comment: I believe it should be your last option, that's why I even didn't mention it in my answer. ASP.Net Core moves away from using web.config toward json configuration files and other configuration sources. If however you still want to try this way, check this article for the start - http://bartwullems.blogspot.com.by/2017/11/webconfig-transformations-in-net-core.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but my answer may help someone, I was working on same thing so I just wanted to share how I resolved it.

1. Set **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** variable in Project Properties - > Debug
2. Create appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json files for each enviornment
3. Keep common configurations in appsettings.json and add/override based on each environment.
4. *Publish through Visual studio.*

   - Right click on Project -> Select Publish
   - Select publish target as folder
   - Publish it to target folder
   - Update ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable in web.config from published code as per your environment.

```
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development"/>
    </environmentVariables>
```